# Can't get simple uneven reflection map working

Tags: reflection

I cant manage to get the reflection work as shown in the reference pictures, I've tried to use everything i could find, bump, normal, clearcoat...

clearcoat won't work bc the surface is very even right? i mean the reflection cant vary because there's no difference in bump?

i tried a displacement map with a noise jpg or generated inside blender, the displacement was too huge and not small enough, couldn't find a way to make it slightly rough or more dense...

Most tutorials show nodes that either dont exist anymore or dotn have the options they used to have, tried alternatives but the reflection is either completely distorted if i set the noise scale in the node based diplacement too high or i simply dont get the result i need...

this is how waf I've come, i made a quite similar version of the real one and projected it onto a densely subdivided circle.

i would love to use the cracked paper texture as a displacement map but the normal map I generated in photoshop has extremely harsh edges in blender even after u blurred it in photoshop...

nothing seems to work, i worked the entire day on this... this is where i ama t atm..[image: my rendering]

These are my references, see the way it reflects? and also the slight unevenness of the whole thing? it seems to be coated for preservation...

[image: reference1][image: reference2]

Any Help is appreciated!
Sincerely Oz

**EDIT** Thanks Gorodon! heres the current state, i guess the rest is fine tuning, prolly adding another layer of reflection.

[image: current version.]

[VIDEO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/borpn.jpg)

Comment: Much more helpful than a screenshot of the result would be a screenshot of the material settings to see where there might be something not correctly connected or which settings could be changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my example to show you what you can do. I guess you're right, it's coated for preservation. I've tried my own take on it.

I gave the *Principled BSDF* a slight (estimated) *Roughness* of 0.2 for the original underlying paint. Since the rim seems to be more of a golden color, I plugged a black and white ring texture into the *Metallic* socket, so that everything is black (or 0) except for the rim which is white (or 1) and therefor metallic.

To recreate the protective coating (which looks quite shiny), I set *Clearcoat* to 1 and *Clearcoat Roughness* to a very low 0.01 (you might even go down to 0).

Since the scratches in the surface come from the broken paint, I thought it would be best to have them in the original surface *Normal* as well as in the *Clearcoat Normal*. I've taken some sort of scratch texture, plugged it into the *Height* socket of a *Bump* node and this into both normal inputs.

For the lighting I took four planes with a strong *Emission* shader to act as lamps and positioned them so that they can be seen in the reflection on the shield. The slight blue reflection comes from an *Environment Texture* which I used for the world.

My result:
[image: medusa]

My node setup:
[image: medusa nodes]

The metallic map:
[image: metal_map]

Comment: Great idea to use the Clearcoat normal input - learned something new today :)

Comment: Well, it has to be there for some reason :D I just figured that if the paint has some serious damage or fissures, than even a clearcoat won't cover them up and make them smooth. Usually several layers of clearcoat help to even out small imperfections on a surface, but the reflections in the original show that this doesn't work here. It's just a pity I don't have a good scratch texture.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am quite new and i need to learn how important it is to work with very low numbers and realize how much can change by 0,x values.

THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: You might consider to accept the answer as correct then. There's always tweaking possible and the result also depends a lot on lighting and environment settings so this is nothing which could be ultimately solved.

Comment: I was looking for some sort of button to mark this as answered or anything but there's nothing i can find to mark your answer as correct. Where are the options to do that ? Thanks in advance.. Sorry I'm new to this Platform.

Comment: The help pages here are a good... well, help :) Check this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Consider the *Clearcoat Normal* socket, which can be fed different data.  Also the *Scale* of any *Displacement* node should be very low.  I'm guessing around .001 to .01 would do it unless your model is much larger than real life scale.